# pagination in same csv file using fast-csv package in nodejs

Tags: mongodb, export-to-csv, node-csv-parse, fast-csv

i am trying to upload my data from mongodb to my csv file but problem is that i only want to add particular amount of data in one sheet and the remaining should be inserted in another sheet in that same  file and i am using fast-csv (nodejs)

I wanted to add my data into csv file using fastcsv in nodejs